# Querying Common Data from Multiple PostgreSQL Databases in Separate Docker Containers for Elasticsearch

Tags: postgresql, docker, elasticsearch

I'm currently developing a microservice application that involves multiple PostgreSQL databases. Each database is housed in a separate Docker container. Here's a brief outline of the tables from these databases:

```
CREATE TABLE "Table1" (
    "Id"   text primary key not null,
    "Col1" text,
    "Col2" text,
    "Col3" text
);

CREATE TABLE "Table2" (
    "Id"   text primary key not null,
    "Col1" text,
    "Col4" text,
    "Col5" text
);

CREATE TABLE "Table3" (
    "Id"   text primary key not null,
    "Col1" text,
    "Col7" text,
    "Col8" text
);

CREATE TABLE "Table4" (
    "Id"   text primary key not null,
    "Col1" text,
    "Col9" text
);
```

Each of these tables resides in a different database. A common column in all these tables is `"Col1"`. My goal is to query all data related to `"Col1"` from these tables and then copy this data into Elasticsearch for further processing.

I'm currently using Docker and Docker Compose for managing these containers. Could you suggest an efficient approach or best practices for querying and aggregating this data from multiple databases in different containers and then transferring it to Elasticsearch?

Comment: How do you propose to aggregate text fields?

Comment: A Postgres database cannot directly access another database. You will need to create a [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html) and/or a set of [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)s.

Comment: If they were be on same database, I would run following query `SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col4, T3.Col7, T4.Col9 FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1 JOIN Table4 T4 ON T1.Col1 = T4.Col1;`. I want to aggregate like that. @1690193